PyTorch Lightning CSVLogger: Why are training and validation losses on different lines?
I have a question about the PyTorch Lightning framework's CSVLogger that has been bugging me for a couple of weeks already.
When I try to log the training and validation losses in their respective training_step and validation_step functions, it seems that the resulting CSV file logs both metrics on separate lines in the metrics.csv file. The file looks like this:



Epoch
train_loss
val_loss




0
0.01
null


0
null
0.02


1
0.005
null


1
null
0.01


2
0.01
null


2
null
0.02



It also shows a step number that I've omitted here, though it's the same for each unique epoch.
Is there any way to place these in a single line in the CSV, using the built-in CSVLogger? I couldn't find anything about this online nor in the documentation.

The following code produces the problem described above:

import torch
from torch.nn import functional as F
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset
import lightning as pl
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris = load_iris()
features, target = iris.data, iris.target

train_features, val_features, train_target, val_target = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.2)

train_features = torch.tensor(train_features).float()
val_features = torch.tensor(val_features).float()
train_target = torch.tensor(train_target).long()
val_target = torch.tensor(val_target).long()

dm = pl.LightningDataModule.from_datasets(
    train_dataset=TensorDataset(train_features, train_target),
    val_dataset=TensorDataset(val_features, val_target),
    batch_size=5,
)

class Model(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer = torch.nn.Linear(4, 3)

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self.layer(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y_hat, y)
        self.log("train_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self.layer(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y_hat, y)
        self.log("val_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.02)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layer(x)

model = Model()
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=10)
trainer.fit(model, dm)

PyTorch Lightning version: 2.2.2

I currently can't reproduce the same result on my end. When are you calling your validation loop?

I'm not sure what you mean. Lightning already handles that internally for me, so it is calling the validation loop just after doing a training epoch, using the dataloader that is defined inside my datamodule. In other news, I've editted my question to include the lightning version I'm using... could be useful

For reference, I've attached an example code snippet that causes the problem

As a workaround, when I'm processing my data I just do
import pandas as pd

log = pd.read_csv("path_to_log_file.csv", sep=',')
log = log.groupby('epoch').mean()  # merge the train and valid rows
log['Epoch'] = log.index  # because "Epoch" gets turned into the index
log.index.name = ''  # to remove the name "Epoch" from the index

Works fine for me in pandas v1.4.2 (not sure about others), since the NaNs are treated as 0 by .mean().

I don't think there is an option to change that. This behavior occurs because both the training and validation loops call log_metrics at different points in time, (even though epoch and step may still overlap). This leads to distinct entries in the CSV file. You can see in the source file, the metrics being appended to the list, and then written to the file with the csv.DictWriter.
